# devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete how to get data portion into submit value

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I've got the autocomplete working in my form, and when I submit it I see the 'value' as part of the post data. Problem is I need the 'data' part in the post also and I can't seem to find out how to accomplish that.

Here's what I'm working with.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
    var countries = [
        { value: 'Palm Bay', data: '1840015094' },
        { value: 'Palm Beach Gardens', data: '1840015125' }
    ];

    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
lookup: countries,
onSelect: function (suggestion) {
  $("location").val(suggestion.value);
  $("city_id").val(suggestion.data);
}
    });
</script>
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="city_id">
<input type="text" placeholder="Location: City, State" data-msg-required="Please enter a city and state." maxlength="100" class="form-control form-control-lg" autocomplete="off" name="location" id="autocomplete">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the onSelect event as per their [docs](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete#usage)

```
<script>
var countries = [
    { value: 'Palm Bay', data: '1840015094' },
    { value: 'Palm Beach Gardens', data: '1840015125' }
];

$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: countries,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        $("#city_id").val(suggestion.data); // Here
    }
});
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="city_id" id="city_id">
<input type="text" placeholder="Location: City, State" data-msg-required="Please enter a city and state." maxlength="100" class="form-control form-control-lg" autocomplete="off" name="location" id="autocomplete">
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply WebCode, I edited my original snippet above to incorporate your suggested changes but it's still not working. I'm not getting a value for city_id in the post data.

Comment: You're getting closer so! `location` and 'city' are not valid html elements. You need to select them using a hash # (when id attribute is set) or dot . (when class attribute is set.) `$("#location").val(suggestion.value);` - notice the hash.... do the same for #city